# Dropdown in webform

Tags: vba, forms, web, dropdown

Thank you for the answer on my previous answer. I’m relative new to VBScript, so I need once more a bit of help. So far I’ve this code, and it works

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

  Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
.Visible = True
.navigate "http://rapido.connect.local/Forms/Refund-Request.aspx"
End With

Do Until IE.readyState = 4
DoEvents
Loop


   'Find & Fill Out Input Box
   IE.document.getElementbyid("p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_Agent_Name_txtText").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Berekeningsblad").Range("j8")
   'Unload IE
endmacro:
   Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

However, the form starts with a dropdown list. I tried several things, but I’m afraid that I’m a bit stuck. I would like to select 1 of the values in the dropdown list.  This is the source code of the dropdown list:

```
<div id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_pnlForm" class="FormPanel" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, &#39;p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_btnOK&#39;)">
        <table class="EditingFormTable"><tr id="Shop"><td class="FieldLabel"><label id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_Shop_lb" class="EditingFormLabel" for="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_Shop_dropDownList">Shop:</label></td><td class="EditingFormValueCell"><div id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_ncpshop" class="EditingFormControlNestedControl editing-form-control-nested-control">
            <select name="p$lt$ctl03$pageplaceholder$p$lt$ctl00$On_lineForm$viewBiz$Shop$dropDownList" id="p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_Shop_dropDownList" class="DropDownField form-control">
                <option selected="selected" value="aal@XX.be">AAL</option>
                <option value="accounts@XX.be">ACC</option>
                <option value="apt@xx.be">APT</option>
                <option value="contactcenter@xx.be">AST CC </option>
                <option value="gent@airstop.be">ASTGNT</option>
                <option value="ATS@xx.be">ATS</option>
                <option value="b2b@xx.be">B2B</option>
                <option value="bra@xx.be">BRA</option>
                <option value="brg@xx.be">BRG</option>
                <option value="bto@xx.be">BTO</option>
                <option value="bts@xx.be">BTS</option>
                <option value="resa@xx.be">ECOM</option>
</select>
```

Comment: There is no question, so there cant be an answer. So you say, the code works... apparently it fills in `Agent_Name_txtText`. Now what do you want to do with the dropdown list? Select a value from dropdown list?

Comment: If so try `IE.document.getElementbyid("p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_Shop_dropDownList").value = [somevalue]`  or  `IE.document.getElementbyid("p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_Shop_dropDownList").selectedIndex = 0` (or any number between 0 and the number of items -1)

Comment: Thank you, the first code works fine!

Answer (score 0):

To select an element from that dropdown list, you should do

`IE.document.getElementbyid("p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_Shop_dropDownList").value = [somevalue]`

where [somevalue] is the value you want to set for that dropdown list.

Alternatively (and I haven't tried), you can try selectedIndex property as follows

`IE.document.getElementbyid("p_lt_ctl03_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl00_On_lineForm_viewBiz_Shop_dropDownList").selectedIndex = [Index]`

where [Index] is a number between 0 and the (number of items - 1).